# Output Buffering Contents After a Script

Tags: php, output, buffering

At the beginning of my script, I have a function that gets JSON content from a remote server that takes a while.  It takes between 1-2 seconds to fetch the data, but that is a ridiculous freeze time for my website's viewers.

What I want to do is to first output all the other content first AFTER the first-line-GET script, and then show  the data involving that JSON call after the data has been received.

ex:

```
<?php

$data = array();
getApiInfo( $user ); //fills $data with info

?>
```

That's the first few lines, then the next is html content that I want to output immediately, but contains some $data info that cannot.

```
<div>
    <img src='images/logo.png' />
    <p>Name: <?php echo $data['name']; ?></p>
</div>
```

Keeping it short, the html afterwards looks sort of like that.  What i want to happen is the image and the 'Name:' show immediately, but the $data['name'] doesn't until the call is complete.

Comment: ajax is non synchronous, which is the approach you need here

Comment: could you give an EFFICIENT example? what I would do is create a variable that contains the JSON array information, and instead of just echoing it in the proper areas, I would have to APPEND it to the proper areas with an after-script, which seems extremely clunky.

Answer (score -1):

Ajax

Your back-end script can fill-in the appropriate div/id/element on your generated html when it's done processing, no refresh.

(Sorry Dagon, didn't see your comment...)